# Have internet but cannot ping ip address

Tags: firewall, ping, timeout

I'm running 2003 Server and have workstations set up to connect to a terminal services session in order to use software stored on the server. we use a program that connects an external entity with us to send documents electronically..both sides have proven to have connection yet we cannot ping each other's ip's...what could be the problem here? (possible firewall config)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your firewall, or their firewall, could be configured to not accept ICMP (Internet Control Message Protocol ) requests, which is a certain type of network traffic ([ping](http://www.activexperts.com/activsocket/tutorials/ping/) is a subset of that type of network traffic)

A lot of companies disable this type of traffic to prevent ping flooding, which could be used as a denial of service type of attack

Look at [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/13780/how-can-i-determine-if-a-machine-is-online-without-using-ping) to see if you could use these techniques if you're trying to determine if a connection is alive w/o using ping
.

Comment: Thanks for the edit izzy... I should know the difference between Your and You're... that's twice I've done that now :(

Comment: It's a pet peeve of mine ;)

Comment: usually mine too, which is why i'm so ashamed of doing it :)

Comment: Heh, I'll chime in on that one also :)

Answer (score 0):

ICMP is being blocked somewhere between your server and the other party's server.  99.9% chance (being liberal on the probability) that it's one or more firewalls.